# How to make a notebook not savable?

Tags: notebooks

How to make a particular notebook not savable?  Optionally, how to do this by evaluating a command in the notebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the menu item Preferences / Advanced / Option Inspector you can easily do that, or from within the notebook evaluate:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], Saveable -> False]
```

will do what you want.
However, notice that Save As still works (not sure if it has to or if this is an intelligent design decision).

Comment: If "Save As" is used and the new file name overwrites the current file, then it means the users deliberately wants to do that?

Comment: So how to do this from menu (not by evaluating a command)?

Comment: @Problemania It is possible to modify the menu items as well, but it is global and it would make for terrible UX and I'd hate if someone were to design a package/application that disabled "Save As" for me. So why don't you actually explain more on why you require this? There are possibly other better ways of achieving what you want

Comment: So, it's impossible to do this from menu for the current in-focus notebook?

Comment: It's similar to `r` and `w` permission settings.  `Saveable` is just more flexible for Mathematica notebooks as users can still evaluate things.  Aren't Mathematica's documentation notebooks set that way or something very similar?

Comment: Yes, documentation notebooks and default stylesheets have `Saveable -> False`

Comment: Is there a way to make it saveable but not to the original file name?

Comment: `SetOptions[InputNotebook[], Saveable -> True, 
  NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> 
     Export[StringReplace[NotebookFileName[], ".nb" -> "good.nb"], 
      EvaluationNotebook[], "NB"]}]`